# Can't locate cron service, how to start it?

Tags: linux, cron, rpm

```
# rpm -qa | grep cron
crontabs-1.10-5.noarch
```

I have the above version of cron installed on my RHEL 6 server.  My crontabs commands aren't reconginzed:

```
    # crontabs -l
-bash: crontabs: command not found
```

My server is remote and not internet connected so troubleshooting is difficult as I can only ssh to it. How can I find the crontabs service to start it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`crontabs-1.10-5.noarch` is not a cron daemon, it's a package containing default crontabs.

```
# rpm -ql crontabs

/etc/cron.daily
/etc/cron.hourly
/etc/cron.monthly
/etc/cron.weekly
/etc/crontab
/usr/bin/run-parts
/usr/share/man/man4/crontabs.4.gz
```

The package containing the default cron daemon on RedHat 6 is `cronie` (and `cronie-anacron`) and the commmand to edit the crontab is called just that: `crontab`.